# Почему DiffUtill работает медленно?

Tags: android

Для того, чтоб обновить данные в адаптере я использовал вот такой метод в адаптере

```
public void setData(@NotNull List<HomeScreenAdapterItem> iData)
{
    mHomeItems = iData;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

потом поменял имплементацию на `DiffUtill`

```
public void setData(@NotNull List<HomeScreenAdapterItem> iData)
{
    MyDiffUtil<HomeScreenAdapterItem> diff = new MyDiffUtil<>(mHomeItems, iData);
    DiffUtil.DiffResult result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diff, false);
    mHomeItems = iData;
    result.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
}
```

Как это работает у меня. Есть экран с `RecyclerView`, когда нажимаю на элемент списка то открывается следующий экран и в нем есть возможность изменить данные списка, включая последовательность элементов.

Так вот при первом подходе при возвращении на первый экран замена элементов списка не заметна, сразу видны обновленные данные, а при подходе с использованием `DiffUtill` открывается экран и я вижу как стрые элементы меняются на новые.

Вопрос

Как сделать, чтоб второй метод работал со скоростью первого?

Comment: так а зачем вам тогда `DiffUtill` если анимация не нужна?

Comment: может вы видите, как меняются элементы, потому что работает анимация (так и должно быть). diffutil обновляет только то, что мзменилось, используя методы notifyItemChanged()  и другие, которые включают анимации действия

Comment: @ermak0ff diffUtill нужен не для анимации, а для правильного обновления элементов, так как метод `notifyItemChanges` очень дорогой в плане ресурсов. Но анимация мне не нужна

Comment: @pavlofff нет так не должно быть, так как у диф утил есть специальный флаг в методе `calculateDiff(... , FALSE)` который и должен отключить анимацию.

Answer (score 1):

DiffUtill нужен для оптимального обновления элементов View в RecyclerView. Обновление происходит только тех View, в которых данные изменились.

Если вас смущает анимация, можно ее выключить:

```
((SimpleItemAnimator) RecyclerView.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
```

Comment: все равно я вижу анимацию . Вот так сделал https://goo.gl/ix7jL5